# Can not transpile ES7 "includes" feature with Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Typescript in a VueJS project which has a subdirectory `functions` for the Cloud Functions to execute on the server side.

I'd like to use the ES2017 feature *Array.prototype.includes* and I thought I'd made that happen by adding the following `tsconfig.json` to my **functions** directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2016", "es2017"],
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

If I go into the **functions** directory and run the `tsc` transpiler it runs without error. Also my vs-code editor does not highlight any issue with the use of "includes". However, following along with the suggested configuration on the Firebase docs I have added the following to my `firebase.json` config file:

```
"functions": {
  "predeploy": "npm --prefix functions run build"
}
```

In turn, my `package.json` in the **functions** directory has the **build** script listed as:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "tslint *.ts && tsc *.ts"
},
```

But when I run `firebase deploy --only functions` it correctly runs the *build* script but it then gives the following error:

> index.ts(44,31): error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

I believe this may be happening because it is incorrectly using the `tsconfig.json` in the root project directory (aka, the one that VueJS is using) instead of the one in the **functions** directory but I'm not entirely sure.

I CAN get around this by changing the build command to:

```
"build": "tslint *.ts && tsc *.ts --lib 'es7'"
```

and this does work but it leaves me feeling I've hacked it a bit. Can anyone point to a better answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that when you specify input files to `tsc` using `tsc *.ts`, the `tsconfig.json` file is ignored.

From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> When input files are specified on the command line, `tsconfig.json`
>   files are ignored.

To fix this run `tsc` without any parameters. This will use your `tsconfig.json` file.